# Maintenance on an existing web forms application that doesn't have a project file

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio, webforms

I am trying to do some maintenance on an existing .net web forms project. Need to re do all the connections to excel and implement sql server. The problem is that there is no VS project file.

Downloaded all the files from the server with ftp and in VS express 2012 did File => open website. After that I added a connection in the web.config (added some new lines for easier read):

```
<add name="Products" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial 
     Catalog=MyDB; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; 
     AttachDbFilename=D:\sites\mySite\home\App_Data\Products.mdf"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Copied and pasted that connection string in another project and opened database explorer where I could see the tables so the connection string is correct.

When opening products.aspx that uses this connection I get the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

I have the following question:

1 How do I create a working project from the files from a web forms application. I have to maintain some other sites as well but the client has no project files for any of them and it takes forever and then some to have these running locally for developing and testing.

2 How do solve the problem with the application not connecting to sql express? I am sort of hoping that the open web is not the best way to do this and creating a project from these files in another way would solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. How do I recover my project file?**

(I'm assuming you are familiar with the difference between a Web Application Project and a Web Site Project, but I'll try to be generic for both)

If your client previously had a Web Application Project (WAP) but no longer has the project file (and likely some of the sources are missing as well, since those are compiled into the DLL before deployment), then you'll have a hard time getting into a Web Application project.  You can try to recover the sources by reverse engineering (or decompiling) your assembly, but that's about it.

If you're working with a Web Site project (WSP), then there is no project file (.csproj).  You can just do File -> Open Website, and that will create a new web site project for you from the directory you specified.  Save the solution file and you're pretty much good to go.

If you do have the source files for a WAP but are just missing the .csproj file, you can try to convert a Web Site Project to a Web Application project (see the MSDN walkthrough titled [Converting a Web Site Project to a Web Application Project in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).  It basically comes down to creating a new project and adding all of the existing files into it, but there are a few other steps that might be useful as well so it's worth a read.

Odds are this is a crappy situation for you, but it's a good chance to educate your clients about the importance of keeping their sources saved somewhere.  Ultimately it's their money.

**2. Why doesn't my database work?**

There's a few reasons why you might encounter errors like this:

- It's possible LocalDB is not installed on the machine where you're running.  For example, if this works on your local (dev) machine, but not when you deploy it, then this is likely the cause.
- Your site is running in IIS.  This is not supported out of the box with LocalDB, but if you follow [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/12/09/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile.aspx) it will walk you through the steps needed.  You can also switch to SQL Express or SQL Server, which do support IIS without workarounds.

Comment: On the same computer when pressing F5 it won't connect but when adding a profile in applicationhost.config and running iisexpress it does connect. The files on the site are basically all the files copied from the project folder except the project file (that's one level higher). Nobody deployed the sites. I will give the client the project files for the new sites and deploy only on the server but most of the work is maintaining the old ones.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I created an empty web project, copied all the files and try to build but then get missing reference. All references that are missing are right there in the project as far as I can see. For example; its complaining about DataAccess.DB in products.aspx.cs that can be found in App_Code\DB.cs When chosing file=> open website and opening the root directory it builds without any warnings or errors.

Comment: Still not getting it, when running the application manually with IIS Express it continues not finding the sql server: "The network path was not found" and "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server" In any other application I can copy and paste the connection string and browse the tables in the Database Explorer. Will post a new question for this.

Comment: Thank you, both you and Warrior are sadly correct that this is the way to create a project from a bunch of aspx and cs files. Sadly after doing all that it won't compile as it's missing dependencies that are right there in the project.

Comment: @HMR: about the comment for missing references.  Since you mention App_Code, I have to assume you're actually working with a Web Site Project, not a Web Application Project.  App_Code is almost never used in a WAP, and was not even supported in that context by VS until recently.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx#summary_of_differences for more details between the two.

Comment: Thank you Jimmy, I was able to compile it. After copying all the files to the empty web application project I added App_Code first then compiled then added UserControls, compiled then the rest.

Answer (score 2):

why not create a new project in visual studio, add a connection to your desired database and test it to make sure it works, then import your downloaded existing files into your newly created visual studio project?

or check out the following two links to common resolutions to the error you are getting

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

and

[7 things to check to resolve  “A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server…”](http://www.sswug.org/articlesection/default.aspx?TargetID=44331)

Comment: Have not tried yet, you mean copy the files to the project and in the solution explorer right click => include in project? The connection does work when I add the application in [my documents]\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config start issexpress and go to the page.

Comment: Have checked out several articles but they all mention network error or server name error. When the application is started in VS with F5 it doesn't connect but on the same computer when I run iisexpress manually and go to the site it does connect. Maybe it has something to do with the way VS starts the web server without localDB support?

Comment: Thank you, both you and Jimmy are sadly correct that this is the way to create a project from a bunch of aspx and cs files. Sadly after doing all that it won't compile as it's missing dependencies that are right there in the project.